# python pandas - how to add two quotation marks in empty cells in one column

Tags: python, pandas

Im trying to modify empty cells in one specific column with two quotation marks (""), but whenever I try it. The pandas add always more quotation marks..

for example:

```
quotes = '""'

sheet01["column"] = sheet01["column"].fillna(quotes)

print(sheet01.head(20))

sheet01.to_csv("newCsv.csv", sep=";", index=False, header=False)
```

when i run this code and do print:

```
sheet01.head(20)
```

I can actually see in VScode that the dataframe has just "" marks in the column

but whenever I open the csvfile it has """""" for some reason..

meaning when there are 2 quotation marks (‍‍‍‍`quotes = '""'`) -> 6 quotation marks
1 quotation mark (`quotes = '"'`) -> 4 quotation marks

but im looking just to make 2 quotation marks in the final csv file

any suggestion how the transition from dataframes to actual csv files work with these quotation marks

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you would want to surround your quotations with ticks

```
df['Column'] = '""'
```

That should just be an example of how to get quotations in your fields.

Similarly, if you only wanted a single quotation you could just put a single one between the two ticks

```
df['Blank'] = '"'
```